# Property "auth" does on exist on type 'FC<{}>' when using next/auth and useSession

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I have what is essentially some boilerplate code from the next/auth docs in my `_app.tsx` file

```
type CustomAppProps = AppProps & {
  Component: NextComponentType & { auth?: boolean }
  pageProps: {
    session: Session
  }
}

function MyApp({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}: CustomAppProps) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        {Component.auth ? (
          <Auth>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Auth>
        ) : (
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        )}
      </ChakraProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}

function Auth({ children }: { children: ReactElement<any, any> }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { status } = useSession({
    required: true,
    onUnauthenticated() {
      router.push(PATHS.LOGIN)
    },
  })

  if (status === 'loading') {
    return <Loader />
  }

  return children
}

export default MyApp
```

However, when using the .auth boolean property on a component I receive a TS error
`Property "auth" does on exist on type 'FC<{}>'`

```
export const HomePage:React.FC = () => {
  const { user, isLoading } = useGetUserDetails()
  if (isLoading || !user) return <Loader />

  return (
    <Box>
      <Text fontSize="2rem" as="p" textStyle="p">
        Welcome: {user.email}
      </Text>
      <Button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign Out</Button>
    </Box>
  )
}

HomePage.auth = true // Property "auth" does on exist on type 'FC<{}>'
```

the functionality is as expected but the error is annoying. next/auth does not provide docs for application of this in Typepscript from what I can see. Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Well, from a TS perspective, you can set the return type `HomePage` to `React.FC & { auth: boolean; }`. Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @JohnPaulR yes thats exactly it. Missed that one. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnPaulR Curious, but wouldn't `React.FC<{ auth: boolean }>` work?

Comment: @Joel An interesting question! Actually, it wouldn't. The generic `React.FC<T>` accepts a type `T` that lets you define the props (`T`) that the function component accepts (these are the parameters of the function). When we  define `HomePage` as `React.FC & { auth: boolean; }`, we're saying: "this value is a function component, but _also_ has aa `auth` property." instead of "value is a function component, which accepts an auth parameter". Lmk if that clarifies.